# библиотека DevIL, что должна возвращать функция ilGenImages?

Tags: c++, opengl, devil

В Tutorial написано мол имя изображения - это просто 32-битное целое число без знака (ILuint) с уникальным значением.
Я как написано в Tutorial написал небольшой код:

```
ILuint GenerateSingleImage()
{
    ILuint ImageName; // The image name to return.
    ilGenImages(1, &ImageName); // Grab a new image name.
    return ImageName; // Go wild with the return value.
}
```

И запустил то что вернула функция через std::cout
B вывело всего навсего цифру 3...
Цифра 3 это и есть 32-битное целое число без знака, которое несет в себе уникальное значение????

Comment: Именно так оно и есть...

Comment: а потом другие функции, которые работают  с изображением, могут получить этот id как указание на то,  с каким именно изображением нужно работать.

Comment: просто где то глубоко внутри есть большая таблица (массив или мапа), где по "индексу" можно узнать разные характеристики этого изображения. Можно конечно было бы дать и указатель, но это сделало бы сильно завязку на внутренности. А так чистая инкапсуляция и полиморфизм, можно полностью поменять внутренности, а пользователю даже перекомпилировать не нужно.